# override constructor in java

Tags: java, swing, constructor

Hello I have a class that draws a star in Java what works like a charm. After this I have extended the Star class to create another star with extendes possibilities ( in this case the color has to be different )

for some reason in my panel when I call the classes and give the parameters with the constructor only the child class color seems to work.

here is my code

```
    public class Star {

    protected int radius;
    protected int xmiddelpunt;
    protected int ymiddelpunt;
    protected static Color color;

    public Star(int radius, int x, int y, Color color) {
        xmiddelpunt = x;
        ymiddelpunt = y;
        this.radius = radius;

        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

and the extended class

```
    public class StarRed extends Star {

    protected int x, y;
    protected static Color color;

    Random red = new Random();

    public StarRed(int radius, int x, int y, Color color) {
        super(radius, x, y, color);

        this.radius = radius;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

the constructor of my panel class is as follows:

```
    ArrayList<Star> stars = new ArrayList<Star>();
ArrayList<StarRed> rs = new ArrayList<StarRed>();

public HeavenPanel() {

    setBackground(Color.blue); // geef het paneel een blauwe kleur


    this.addMouseWheelListener(this); // set de mouselistener


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stars.add(new Star (r.nextInt(30 + 50), r.nextInt(10 + 701), r.nextInt(10 + 701), Color.yellow));
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        rs.add(new StarRed(40, r.nextInt(30 + 50), r.nextInt(30 + 50), Color.red));
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are extending the class, it is to profit from the work that is already done by the parent. So, don't duplicate in `StarRed` all the attributes you already manage in `Star` (all of them).

Comment: You should post what you do with those lists, otherwise we don't know what is happenning the GUI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First problem:

```
protected static Color color;
```

That means that field (which you've got two of...) is shared across the whole type. I would have expected this to be an *instance* field, so different stars can be different colours. Instead, all stars are the same colour, unless you've got some code in `StarRed` which uses the `color` field, in which case you may have *two* colours of stars... but it's still not right.

Second problem: your `StarRed` class declares its own fields for `x`, `y`, and `color`, despite them also being declared in the superclass. You're then setting the value of the superclass's `radius` field despite that already having been set in the superclass constructor.

Basically it's all a bit confused at the moment. You should work out what information is associated with the type rather than any specific instance (in which case that should be a static field) and what information is associated with individual instances (in which case those should be instance fields). You should almost *never* use the same field name in a subclass and a superclass - and personally I'd suggest making all fields private (except possibly for constants).

Finally, why would the `StarRed` constructor want to take a `Color` at all? Shouldn't it always be red?

Comment: ah thanks! ye i was a bit confused but the whole problem was the static! i removed that and the x and y in the constructor of my subclass, thanks a lot!

Comment: one think i Don't understand... why can i not give a this.color = color.red; in my subclassconstructor without making it static in the superclass?

Comment: @Reshad: You should be able to, while it's a protected field. (I'd suggest *not* setting it in the subclass though, given that you're already setting it in the superclass.) Basically, only store any piece of information once, and only set it in one place.

Answer (score 5):

You are overriding the static variable color.

Static keyword means all instances of the class have the same colour.

So the parent and child are referring to same static variable.

Therefore since you set child color later only child color works.

Change your code and remove static

Comment: You can't *override* a field. The parent and the child actually refer to *different* static variables, as each class declares its own static variable.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, first remove the static from `public static Color color`.
Also you do not need to redeclare the fields of `Star` in the `StarRed` class. From your `Random red = new Random()` statement I assume that you want to make some calculations in `StarRed` to determine the tone of red, so you add another protected Star constructor, which omits setting the color. You use that for the `StarRed`. The public constructor of `Star` will use it, too, but additionally set the star's color.

Your code would look like this:

```
public class Star {

    protected int radius;
    protected int xmiddelpunt;
    protected int ymiddelpunt;
    protected Color color;

    public Star(int radius, int x, int y, Color color) {         
        this(x,y,radius)
        this.color = color;
    }

    protected Star(int radius, int x, int y) {
        xmiddelpunt = x;
        ymiddelpunt = y;
        this.radius = radius;

        this.color = color;
    }


}
```

and the extended class

```
public class StarRed extends Star {

    Random red = new Random();

    // Overrides Star constructor
    public StarRed(int radius, int x, int y, Color color) {
        super(radius, x, y); // Call protected superconstructor (radius, x,y)
        // Now we set the color, so the star is red (example code!)
        this.color = Color.RED;
        // You can still use color e.g. to define blue and green components of this.color

    }
}
```

By the way: If you e.g. remove the color variable from the StarRed constructor, then you just would *overload* the `Star` constructor.

I hope it helped :)

Comment: if i can add something, remove  this.color = color; from your second constructor of Star